# Why are the buttons on my UIAlert duplicating?

Tags: swift, alert

I'm attempting to build an app using Swift that's similar to the Notes app, but I'd like to have an Alert pop up when the user presses the "+" button to add a new Note - and the Alert would prompt the user to enter a name. The name is then added as a new row in the underlying table. So far, I've been able to do this, but every time i click the "+" sign, the buttons I've added to the Alert get re-added. In other words, the Alert should have an "OK" & a "Cancel" button. But on the 2nd time the Alert pops up, there are 2 "OK" buttons, and 2 "Cancel" buttons, and so on. Any ideas how i can fix this? Thanks for your help!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

var data:[String] = []

//create alert controller
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Name", message: "Enter a name", preferredStyle: .alert)



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.title = "Notes"

    //create "add" button
    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addAlert))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    //create edit button so we can delete rows
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
    load()

}

//function to add new note. This code is executed when the "Add" button is clicked

func addNote()
{
    //code to prevent being able to add rows while in edit mode
    if (table.isEditing) {
        return
    }

    let textField = self.alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
    let name:String = textField.text!
    data.insert(name, at: 0)
    let indexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    table.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    save()
}

func addAlert()
{
    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Name"})
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //grab value from the text field and print when user clicks OK
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
        let textField = self.alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
        print("Text Field: \(textField.text!)")
        self.addNote()
    }))
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
    cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    //puts table in edit mode
    table.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
}

//function to delete rows from table
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    table.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    save()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detail", sender: nil)


}

func save()
{
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "notes")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}

func load()
{
    if let loadedData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "notes") as? [String]
    {
        data = loadedData
        table.reloadData()
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put alert.addAction before presenting the alert. Try this code in addAlert() method

```
func addAlert()
{
 var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Name", message: "Enter a name", preferredStyle: .alert)
 alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Name"})


    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
        let textField = self.alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
        print("Text Field: \(textField.text!)")
        self.addNote()
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Ok so I tried doing the above, and I'm still getting the same result... Any other ideas???

Comment: var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Name", message: "Enter a name", preferredStyle: .alert)

Declare alert inside the addAlert() method. I have updated that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to present the alert only after adding the actions(Buttons).

```
    func addAlert()
    {
    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Name"})
    //grab value from the text field and print when user clicks OK
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
        let textField = self.alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
        print("Text Field: \(textField.text!)")
        self.addNote()
    }))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Ok so I tried doing the above, and I'm still getting the same result... Any other ideas???

Comment: @thedragon19 Well...Im not getting that problem, can you attach a ss of what u r getting? Also rather than declaring alert as a global variable, better to declare the variable in add alert().

Comment: In your qn, u mentioned, OK and cancel button, but in your code I didn see any cancel button.

Comment: here's a screenshot. Regarding the cancel button, I just haven't added it yet because I haven't even been able to get the "OK" button to work properly - figured I'd do one step at a time.
Also, when I declare the alert variable in the "add alert()" function instead of globally, it throws me more errors.

Comment: I had to add the screenshots to the original post btw. Thanks for your help.